# How to make a file loading progress bar for the rails form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I'm trying to make a form that has an title, email, content and file upload fields. When the user click submit the uploaded file is saved in the database and the link with the location and hashed name is send to admin. That all works but the files that users are gonna upload are big and I would like to have some loading bar. I know there are many similar questions on stackoverflow but I was not able to make it work. 
First I set two routes:

get "message", to: "messages#index"

post "message_create", to: "messages#create"

Over the first I get the form:

```
<%= form_tag(message_create_path, :method=>'post', class: "section form", :multipart => true) do %>

    <fieldset class="form__fieldset">

        <div class="form__field">
            <%= text_field_tag 'name', nil, class: 'input', placeholder: 'Name', id: 'name' %>
        </div>

    <div class="form__field">
        <%= text_field_tag 'email', nil, class: 'input', placeholder: 'Email', id: 'email' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form__field">
        <%= text_area_tag 'content', nil, class: 'input textarea', rows: '10', placeholder: 'content', id: 'content' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form__field">
            <%= file_field_tag 'file', id: 'input_file' %>
    </div>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="js-percent">0%</div >
</div>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form__fieldset">
        <%= submit_tag 'send', :class => "btn btn--dark-ghost", :id => "submit" %>
    </fieldset>
<%end%>
```

The form should then post to the second route. 
To make the loading progress visible I try to use this:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
        var file_data = $("#input_file").get(0).files[0]
        $.ajax({
            xhr: function()  {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                //Upload progress
                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    $(".js-percent").text(String(percentComplete*100) + "%")
                }
            }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
    url: "message_create",
    type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(file_data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

When I try to submit the file the text 0% joust jumps to 100% but I see that the browser is still uploading.
I can't make it work because I don't know ajax so please help me fix this loading progress problem and I'd appreciated if you can recommend me some good tutorials for learning Ajax. 
Thank you!

Comment: Why dont use a jquery plugin for that?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload